# If $\left\langle b,c\right\rangle =\left\langle c,a\right\rangle=\langle a,b\times c\rangle =\dfrac {1} {2}$, find $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose $\vec {a},\vec {b},\vec {c}$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.

If $\left\langle b,c\right\rangle =\left\langle c,a\right\rangle=\left\langle a,b\times c\right\rangle=\dfrac {1} {2}$  then find $\left\langle a,b\right\rangle$.

I thought the angle between $\overrightarrow{b}$ and $\overrightarrow{c}$ equals to angle between $\overrightarrow{c}$ and $\overrightarrow{a}$ which measures $60^{\circ}$.
and
$\left\langle a,b\times c\right\rangle=\left\langle a\times b,c \right\rangle=|a||b|\sin k|c|\cos m$

how can I continue?

Comment: I am not sure there is a single answer to this. Even in the simplest case where the $b$ and $c$ are in the $xy$-plane, there are two solutions that are equally valid. Was there any more information given?

Comment: @TerraHyde by symmetry, the case you considered is in fact the only case.

Comment: @Macavity I was thinking of pointing that out, but I was not entirely certain if it was correct while I was leaving the comment.

Comment: @TerraHyde  Its correct as both scalar products are invariant to translations and rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the identity (which you may have to prove)
$$[\mathbb{a,b,c}]^2=\begin{vmatrix}\mathbb{a.a} & \mathbb{a.b} & \mathbb{a.c} \\ \mathbb{b.a} & \mathbb{b.b} & \mathbb{b.c} \\\mathbb{c.a} & \mathbb{c.b} & \mathbb{c.c} \end{vmatrix}$$

You should get two possible values for $\mathbb{a\cdot b}$

Comment: $ < a,b>=k$
and $
\begin{align*} & \dfrac {3} {4}-\left( k\left( k-\dfrac {1} {4}\right) \right) +\dfrac {1} {2}\left( \dfrac {k} {2}-\dfrac {1} {2}\right) =\dfrac {1} {4}\end{align*} 
\& k=\dfrac {1\pm 2\sqrt {5}} {4}$  I hope it is correct

Comment: @St3114 The answer is right...